# Clojure: Create or update Map values in a vector

Tags: clojure, insert-update

I want to update some values in my vector.

To change this :

```
[{:key 0, :values {:value1 1, :value2 100}} {:key 1, :values {:value1 5, :value2 300}}]
```

In this:

```
[{:key 0, :values {:value1 1, :value2 100}} {:key 1, :values {:value1 6, :value2 500}}]
```

I'm trying to do something like that, without success:

```
(if (contains? myvectors myId)
  (do
    (assoc ((myvectors myId) :values) :value2 500));not working
  )
  (do
    (def myvectors (merge myvectors {:key myId :values {:value1 1 :value2 300}}))
  )
)
```

Comment: could you please elaborate more on your goal. it is really unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't know much about this language. 

Basically I wanted to create a multidimensional array.

Something like : array[myId] = ['value1' => x, 'value2' => a]
array[myId2] = ['value1' => y, 'value2' => b]

Comment: If the `:key` is equal to `1`, then add inside `:value` `1` to `:values` and `200` to `:values2`? Then you state you want to _create_ something - it looks like you want _change_ something. It would really help, if you could formulate the problem in a way, that actually reflects your problem. It's hard to give proper advice, if the question does not clearly show your problem.

Comment: Also never `def` other than at ns level. From your attempts it looks like you are assuming, that `myvector` is a global variable you can replace in your function.  This is not how Clojure works. Clojure uses immutable data and want you to write in a functional style. Write a function, that takes the data as input, derive the result from that data and return the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```clj
(def v
  [{:key 0 :values {:value1 1 :value2 100}} {:key 1 :values {:value1 5, :value2 300}}])

(defn update-values [v k value1 value2]
  (mapv (fn [{:keys [key] :as m}]
          (cond-> m
            (= key k) (assoc :values {:value1 value1 :value2 value2})))
        v))

(update-values v 1 6 500)
;; => [{:key 0 :values {:value1 1 :value2 100}} 
;;     {:key 1 :values {:value1 6 :value2 500}}]
```

If possible I would change your data structure so you can make better use of core functions, for example a map from key to values:

```clj
(def m
  {0 {:value1 1 :value2 100}
   1 {:value1 5 :value2 300}})

(assoc m 1 {:value1 6 :value2  500})
;; => {0 {:value1 1 :value2 100}
;;     1 {:value1 6 :value2 500}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is change the second element (map) in your vector as per your before/after examples, you can do something like this:

```
(let [m [{:key 0, :values {:value1 1, :value2 100}} 
         {:key 1, :values {:value1 5, :value2 300}}]]
  (update-in m [1 :values] merge {:value1 6 :value2 500}))
=> [{:key 0, :values {:value1 1, :value2 100}} {:key 1, :values {:value1 6, :value2 500}}]
```

where [`update-in`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in) updates the second element in the vector (index 1 in the `[1 ...]` expression - 0 based indexing) and on that element updates the `:values` key. For that value (`{:value1 5, :value2 300}`) we call the [merge](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge) function. `update-in` will send in the old value (again, the old value is at this point `{:value1 5, :value2 300}`) as the first argument to `merge` and then we send in `{:value1 6 :value2 500}` as the second argument. Since later arguments to `merge` "win", the map values we send in will overwrite the ones already in your data.

Comment: For this specific example I would call `assoc` instead of `merge` since there's nothing to be merged; `(update-in m [1 :values] assoc :value1 6 :value2 500))`

Comment: This also assumes that the position in the vector is equal to the `:key` which might not be true generally.

Comment: True on both accounts. I opted for `update` as I think it's a tad more robust as that would not break the pattern in case the target map at some point in the future had additional key/value pairs. And yes, I agree, updating a vector by index is brittle.

Comment: I opted for `merge`...what I get for typing things up on a phone.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what's your goal, but I've tried to come up with something general enough:

```clj
(def data [{:key 0, :values {:value1 1, :value2 100}}
           {:key 1, :values {:value1 5, :value2 300}}])

(reduce
  (fn [v {:keys [key] :as row}]
    (conj v
          (cond-> row
                  (= key 1)
                  (assoc :values {:value1 6, :value2 500}))))
  []
  data)
=> [{:key 0, :values {:value1 1, :value2 100}} {:key 1, :values {:value1 6, :value2 500}}]
```

This will `reduce` over the input sequence by changing the given `row` only based on some `cond`ition. Since it looks like you want to change based on the `key` I've added the condition `(= key 1)` but this can be easily adapted to any condition for anything that's contained in the `row`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try that.
I don't know this language, more used to PHP.
Basically I wanted to create a multidimensional array. Something like : array[myId] = ['value1' => x, 'value2' => a] array[myId2] = ['value1' => y, 'value2' => b], which can be updated depending on the key (MyId1 or MyId2)

Comment: No worries, I think there's no need to use the map of maps then; you can:
`[{:value1 1 :value2 100} {:value1 5, :value2 300}]`
Then you can `(assoc-in data [1 :value1] 6)` which is nice and clean!